# Is there a race or trait that grants proficiency in Net?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

In Pathfinder, is there a race (including alternate racial traits) or a trait that grants a bonus proficiency in Net (or in a weapon of choice that can include Net?) What about a class that grants a bonus proficiency in it?

I seem to remember some way to do this other than using a feat for it, but can't find it. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that since a net is a touch attack, you can often hit with it even while taking the nonproficiency penalty.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Spirit of the Waters](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/elf) elven alternate racial trait gives proficiency in longsword, trident, and net.

Also the [Huntmaster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier/archetypes/paizo---cavalier-archetypes/huntmaster) cavalier archetype.

More generally for exotic weapon proficiency, the half-elf [Ancestral Arms](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/half-elf) alternate racial trait gives you a free exotic weapon proficiency for which you could choose net.

There's other more long and painful ways - like a [dwarven oracle favored class option](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/dwarf#TOC-Favored-Class-Options) lets you reduce the nonproficiency penalty by 1 each time you level, so by level 4 you could be net-proficient. Kitsune and Hobgoblins have an option like that too.

There's a bunch of third party classes that give net proficiency, not sure if you just want Paizo-published or not but search in the classes on the d20pfsrd if you want those.

Answer (score 5):

The [grippli](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-grippli/) get a net racial proficiency

Comment: This is very close to a link only answer. Adding the manual and page of this race might help prevent link rot.